# Negative Eigenvalues of the Hessian

Tags: energy, condensed-matter, computational-physics, simulations, ferromagnetism

I am calculating the eigenvalues of the Hessian for a ferromagnetic system. My energy has the zeeman term, a nearest neighbor exchange term, and a dipole-dipole term. I create the hessian where my only degrees of freedom are the polar angles of the spins since we don't expect there to be any out of plane magnetization.  To evaluate this matrix, I get my spin states from a micromagnetic simulator which solves the LLG equation.

Now, when I diagonalize the matrix, almost half of my eigenvalues (~3000/7225) are negative. I interpret this as it being an order ~3000 saddle point but from attempting to look this up, the chemists seem to say that this has no meaning and any transition point should only be a single or double saddle point. Would this many negative eigenvalues make sense?

Comment: More details are needed before an answer is possible. I assume that the "LLG  equation" is is the Landau-Lifshitz-Gilbert equation, but what quantity related to this equation are you calculating the Hessian of?

Comment: I am calculating the Hessian solely using the Energy Equation, E = E_exchange + E_zeeman + E_{dipole-dipole} and the simulations purpose is to get all the magnetization cosines of the spins so that I can put the spin information into the Hessian.

Comment: I don't see what information you can get from the Hessian of the energy functional evaluated on solutions of time dependent LLG equation. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I am trying to see how many configurations or "paths" there are to clearing an energy barrier.  Solving the LLG equation gives me what the spins are doing for a particular sample shape and applied field.  I can either get what all the spins are doing at the bottom of the energy well or at the top of the barrier.  I then take this information and use those thetas and replace the thetas that are in my Hessian since you need a state to evaluate the Hessian.

Comment: What energy well?  Please explain your problem from the start. LLG is a one-dimensional soliton equation with some damping. It does not have an "energy well"

Comment: I have a square sample I am simulating, the magnetization has multiple ground states separated by barriers. Both experiment and simulations support this.  I am using the simulations because they tell me what all the individual spins are doing in the square sample. Those spins that my simulation calculate I put into the Hessian since you need a state to evaluate the Hessian.  My main questions is that I get about 40% of my eigenvalues as negative regardless of the cell sizes I use. That seems like too much to me but it may not be.

Comment: Does you system go from ferro- to anti-ferro as you change the relative strength of the dipole and exchange forces?    If so, it sounds as if you are (for example) really in a Neel anti-ferro phase, but your  "solver" has found a highly unstable, but stationary energy, ferromagnetic  spin configuration. In such a state you would expenct 1/2 the Hessian ev's to be negative, as the spin are parallel, but want to be anti-parallel (or anti-parallel and want to be parallel).